# how to unit test Aspect annotation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-aop

I have defined an Aspect and it will be used when the method is annotated. Please see the sample code below

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PredefinedCheck {

}

@Aspect
@Component
public class PredefinedAspect {
    
    @Before("@annotation(PredefinedCheck)")
    @SneakyThrows
    public void check(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        ......
        log.debug("hello!!");
    }
}

@Service
public class ActionService {
     
     @PredefinedCheck
     public MyEntity updateMyEntity(AuthenticationJwtToken authToken, EntityUpdateRequest request) {
          ......
     }
}
```

Now, the question is how can I unit test my PredefinedAspect code? I thought unit testing the `updateMyEntity` method will trigger it, but it didn't (I debugged and it not hit the break point. Also, the sonarqube doesn't shows the code being covered). Please advise.

Comment: You need to run this as a Spring-Test so that it loads the context, otherwise that Aspect will never fire.

did you check this link?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389015/junit-tests-for-aspectj

Comment: What you want is not a unit test, but an integration test. For a unit test, you should not need any DI container or Spring test magic. Besides, you cannot "unit-test an aspect annotation", you should rephrase your question title. An annotation does absolutely nothing, it just sits there. The aspect is what you want to test.

Comment: Two general answers I wrote about [how to unit-test an aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407336/1082681) and [how to integration-test an aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453156/1082681). You can use the former for both Spring AOP and native AspectJ. But the latter mostly applies to native AspectJ, because I use aspects outside of Spring. Anyway, the basic approach is the same, you would only use some kind of Spring testing infrastructure, like @Dan suggested. How to exactly test your aspect, depends on the details you are hiding from us behind "..." - not very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps**

1. Create under src/test/ root project, SpringBootApplication class, that will start the context(loading/registering the AOP) for test purpose.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { PredefinedAspect.class } )
public class ApplicationTest {
    public void main(String args[]) {
        SpringBootApplication.run(ApplicationTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. Enable your test with SprintBootTest annotation, with the Application context above.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
```

3. If your project enables some configuration, such Hibernate / Database and you aren't interested test it, exclude with EnableAutoConfiguration annotation. For example:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Full example:

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;


@Service
class ActionServiceFake {
    @PredefinedCheck
    public MyEntity updateMyEntity(AuthenticationJwtToken authToken, EntityUpdateRequest request) {
    }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class PredefinedAspectTest {
    @SpyBean
    PredefinedAspect predefinedAspect;

    @Autowired
    ActionServiceFake actionServiceFake;

    @Test
    public void shouldCheckOneTimesBefore() {
        // exercise ...
        actionServiceFake.updateMyEntity(new AuthenticationJwtToken(), new EntityUpdateRequest());

        // expectation ...
        verify(predefinedAspect, times(1)).check(any(JoinPoint.class));
    }
}
```

You can use the external ActionService class, but, don't forget add it Application Context base classes list.

Comment: Nice answer.  Like I said in my comment a few months ago, this is however an integration test (starting a full Spring Boot container), not a unit test. Both types of test make sense. My link to how to unit-test an aspect enables you to test the aspect logic as such in isolation without requiring any Spring magic or expensive containers. The unit test runs in milliseconds.

Comment: @kriegaex, I agree, you're absolutely right. Really this is an integration test and I would have emphasize about it. With regard to [how to unit-test an aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407336/1082681), I did like that.